# QWidget - Always resizing by window size

Tags: qt, qwidget

I have a QTextEdit Control and I want it to resize widh window size always.
My solution is using a timer, but that won't be really elegant, so I thought, there must be a property.

Could you help me? Uncle Google wasn't any help.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I've tried to write in proper English, but I'm from germany, so there could be some mistakes. I hope you excuse it.

Comment: Animations can be done with this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpropertyanimation.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use your Windows `resizeEvent` to update the size of your `QTextEdit`.

Read more about the `resizeEvent` in the QWindow documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#resizeEvent

And here is an Example:

```
void MyQWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
   QWindow::resizeEvent(event);
   this->resizeTextEdit(); // In this function you update the size
}
```

Comment: I just assumed you are using C++ for the Example. If you are using Python just read this as Pseudocode ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Generaly, You can do that just with layouts, just wrap the QTextEdit inside one, (QVBoxLayout or QHBoxLayout for example).
Or if you have a specific case, you can use the method prposed by Mailerdaimon.